# Unable to unselect divs (after been selected) using jquery-ui selectable

Tags: jquery, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using Jquery-selectable-ui, everything works fine, except when divs (the nested divs inside-> main div(ID=Sunday)) have been selected, if I try to unselect then I must unselect twice, else divs will not be unselected..(while I scroll+select for the first time - divs change their color but after I release the mouse's grip, the div's color is the same, only in the second time divs are unselected)
The problem is that class:''click-selected'' will be removed only at the second time I unselect my divs.
Hope I am clear...
Am I missing something? How can I solve this?

//CSS

```
#Sunday .ui-selected {
    background: #0cb7e3;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div class="ui-selectable" id="Sunday">
    <div class="ui-selectee" id="00:00" rel='00:00' count='1'>00:00</div>
    <div class="ui-selectee" id="01:00" rel='01:00' count='2'>01:00</div>
    <div class="ui-selectee" id="02:00" rel='01:00' count='3'>02:00</div>
<div>
```

//Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $("#Sunday").bind("mousedown", function (event) {
        return event.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.selected).hasClass('click-selected')) {
                $(ui.selected).removeClass('ui-selected click-selected');
            } else {
                $(ui.selected).addClass('click-selected');
            }
        },
        unselected: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.unselected).removeClass('click-selected');
        },
        stop: function () {
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                var id = this.id;
                var count = $("#Sunday").find("div[rel='" + id + "']").attr("count");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your code is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/LTLr5/

Comment: Well I rechecked my code and I found that after a few times, if I try to unselect my divs they will stay selected because class - 'click-selected' remain althought I unselect my divs..

Comment: working fine means no worries :), but in the fiddle you could see that the class `click-selected` is removed when you click on, already selected onces

Comment: Thank you I do understand that, but for no reason after few clicks the click-selected class is not removed... and I checked it many times I dont know why.. Well if you can't see a problem, you can't solve a problem :), thank you.